# Handle undefined values to search Firestore database

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search page with about 10 possible fields but not every field is required to search. But how can I build the query so that it doesn't look at the values that aren't filled out (and are undefined)?

I can't write an if statement in typescript (which I was trying first) because then I would have to write more then 10 different possible queries which just doesn't seem very efficient.

So how can I remove the undefined entries and reuse the same query?

I really don't have a clue on how to even start trying this so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

[Search screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZu9X.png)

Query:

```
this.itemsCollectionHouse = this.afs.collection<House>('houses', ref=> ref.where('garden', '==', true).orderBy('name'));
```

So the screenshot shows the screen where the user can enter input in the search fields. Then the query is just a small part of what I want to do because I wasn't sure how to proceed. But I need to be able to execute a search query when all fields are entered, but also when one or more fields from the search screen are empty / undefined.

For instance if **garden** wasn't selected by the user and was undefined, how would I execute the query without that variable but still searching the fields that are filled out?

Comment: If you want useful answers you need to provide us with more information. Show us your input data and the desired query.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I added some more info to my original question, I hope that clarifies things a bit. Don't hesitate to ask if it's not clear enough. I'm not sure how to beter describe what I want to achieve. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not talking to Firebase until the submit button is clicked (vs talking to Firebase on keyup and onchange events). So, your task is actually a simple one.

Unless you have a solid reason not to, use JavaScript. Also, use Firestore as it supports [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

```
var myArray = [];
var whereString = "";
if(selectOne.value){
  myArray.push('"state", "==", ' + selectOne.value);
} 
if(selectTwo.value){
  myArray.push('"color", "==", ' + selectTwo.value);
} 
if(inputOne.value){
  myArray.push('"population", "<", ' + inputOne.value);
} 

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  whereString = whereString + ".where(myArray[i])"
}

myRef = firebase.firestore() + whereString
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't get how it's that simple. :)

I'm using JavaScript and Firestore. But when the values are undefined I can't use them to query Firestore because the values there are always true or false, so when the value from the search field is 'undefined' it should return all the documents that have 'true' or 'false' for that field.

The only way I can see how to do it is using an 'if' clause to check al the values individually and build different queries based on the result, but that seems very inefficient.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to proceed whit the 'myRef' variable to query the correct collection / document. I didn't find an answer in the documentation. Should I be doing something like this: 

      var myRef = firebase.firestore() + whereString
      this.itemsCollectionHouse = this.afs.collection<House>('house', myRef)

This gives an error by the way on the last line, so I'm definitely doing something wrong. :)